# Laravel trying to add to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm new on Laravel framework. I'm trying to save from forms to database.

Example:

- Input STEAM_ID:
- Input Access:

Controller:

```
public function admins_add()
{
    $serveradmins = DB::table('server_admins')->first();
    $this->title('Add admins');
    $this->pageView('servers::admins_add', ['serveradmins' => $serveradmins]);
    DB::table('server_admins')->insert(
        array(
            $serveradmins->auth = Input::get('steam-id'),
            $serveradmins->access = Input::get('access'),
            $serveradmins->password = 'nopass',
            $serveradmins->flags = 'ce',
            $serveradmins->added_by = Input::get('added_by')
        )
    );
    $serveradmins->save();
    return Redirect::back();
}
```

Views:

```
<div class="page page-servers page-servers-admin-form">
    <form method="POST" action="/admin/servers/admins/create" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">STEAM ID</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input name="steam-id" type="text" id="steam-id">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="access" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Teisės</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <input name="access" type="hidden" value="" id="access">
                <select id="access" name="access"><option value="" selected="selected">-</option>
                    <option value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuv">Owner</option>
                    <option value="bcdfijmnopqruv">Admin</option>
                    <option value="3" disabled>PREMIUM</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-actions">
            <button type="submit" name="_form_submit" class="btn btn-default" value="1">
                <i class="fas fa-save "></i> 
                SAVE!
            </button>
            <button type="button" onclick="document.location.href='/admin/servers/admins'"  class="btn btn-default">
                <i class="fas fa-times "></i> Cancel
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</section>
```

And my routes:

```
    ModuleRoute::get('admin/servers/admins/create', 'AdminServersController@admins_add');
    ModuleRoute::post('admin/servers/admins/create', 'AdminServersController@admins_add');
```

Dont be mad on my if my code is terrible, i'm new on laravel and really like it! Thanks guys for helping :)

Comment: Can you give a quick explanation as to what exactly is wrong and what step you think is incorrect?  If you have any errors, can you also state what those are?

Comment: input and the select use same id and name "access" ? and route get/post to same method ?

Comment: @kenken9999 has a good point. Your request sent to admins_add() will use the name of the html element as the key. Make sure names and ids of all html elements are unique.

Comment: may be someone can make a very simple run down example, better without all css, after you see the data saved to db, then go back to modify your view and add more inputs

Comment: empty form with one input only(without all css) > route > controller method (Request $request) > save the $request->input() to db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First: Why do you want to execute `admins_add()` in your `get` route? Create a function called `index()` for easier understanding and tell that function to return the view like

```
public function index() {
$serveradmins = DB::table('server_admins')->first();
return view('viewname')->with('serveradmins', $serveradmins);
}
```

Then your `admins_add()`should look like this:

```
public function admins_add(Request $request)
{
       ServerAdmin::create([
        'auth' => $request->steam-id,
        'access' => $request->access,
        'password' => 'nopass',
        'flags' => 'ce',
        'added_by' => $request->added_by
        ]);     

    return Redirect::back();
}
```

And before executing generate the `ServerAdmin` Model via CLI ( `php artisan make:model ServerAdmin`) and inside this model you change the fillables to

```
protected $fillable = [
          'auth',
          'access',
          'password',
          'flags',
          'added_by'
          ];
```

and set

```
protected $table = 'server_admins';
```

Edit: As N Mahurin mentioned in the comments - take this solution for practicing with Laravel. Mass Assignments have a heavy security risk. Read here about it:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: You may want to add that mass assignment, while convenient, has security vulnerabilities outlined in https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Sure and good that you mention it. But I think for someone to start developing with Laravel its important to understand Eloquent correct and this is imo the easiest start. But @op keep his advice in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Your insert is off. It should be key => value pairs (where the key is the column name in the DB). Try

```
DB::table('server_admins')->insert([
    'auth' => Input::get('steam-id'),
    'access' => Input::get('access'),
    'password' => 'nopass',
    'flags' => 'ce',
    'added_by' => Input::get('added_by')
    ]);
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#inserts for more info. You can also go the eloquent route and do:

```
$serverAdmin = new ServerAdmin();
$serverAdmin->auth = Input::get('steam-id'),
$serverAdmin->access = Input::get('access'),
$serverAdmin->password = 'nopass',
$serverAdmin->flags = 'ce',
$serverAdmin->added_by = Input::get('added_by')
$serverAdmin->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. Now i'm getting really strange error: hash_equals(): Expected user_string to be a string, null given